# Multiple instances of Windows Wireless 802.11 Extensibility Framework. Why?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, task-manager

I counted the number of instances of this process on a particularly bad day: I have 120 instances of Windows Wireless 802.11 Extensibility Framework running. They just pile up for reasons I can't determine, each one using 2mb of RAM, and mostly 0% CPU.

Halp. Any suggestions?

Windows 8.1, 6GB Ram, Intel Core i5